# how to place a condition over a column name which is created by aliasing

Tags: sql-server

How do I place a condition on a column if I am making the column at run time?  Suppose I am having an employee table which has `empname` and `empsal`.

Now I am writing a query like:

```
select empname, (empsal*2) as 'doublesalary' from employee where doublesalary > 30000
```

I can do this simply like:

```
select empname, (empsal*2) as 'doublesalary' from employee where (sal*2) > 30000
```

but what if I want to place a condition over that aliased column??

Is there any way to do it??

Comment: for knowledge sake,select * from 
(select empname, (empsal*2) as 'doublesalary' from employee)t4 where doublesalary > 30000.Else this query is not ok.better do it (empsal*2) > 100000

Comment: You should do `select empname, (empsal*2) as 'doublesalary' from employee where empsal > 15000` as this is sargable.

Answer (score 1):

If avoiding code duplication is really important in this example, you could **[create a view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)**.

If that seems like too much work, you can select from a select like this:

```
select empname, doublesalary
from (
    select empname, (empsal*2) as doublesalary from employee
) as employee2
where doublesalary > 30000;
```

Here is a fiddle for the **[select from a select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64ffe/3/3)** answer.